# Calling Watson Discovery API from behind a HTTP Proxy server using Python SDK

Tags: python, proxy, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'm using Watson Python SDK https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk to send the search request to Watson Discovery service, but I'm behind a http proxy and not able to reach to the Watson Discovery service.

Could you please advice me to modify to execute this python script(watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) in HTTP proxy environment ?

```
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1

discovery = DiscoveryV1(
  username=username,
  password=password,
  version="2017-11-07"
)

collection = discovery.get_collection(environment_id, collection_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set_http_config() function provided

```
http_config = {
    "proxies": {
        "https": "URL",
        "http": "URL"
    }
}
discovery.set_http_config(http_config)
```